# How to amend or delete a commit on a remote git repo?

Tags: git

If I have commited a change on my local repo, then git push'ed the change. I know you can amend and remove commits to a local repo, but what commands do I enter to do something similar for my remote repo:

1) Delete my last push from the remote repo.
2) Amend my last push to the remote repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to force push your new reference:

```
vim yourfile
git add yourfile
git commit --amend --no-edit
git push -f origin yourbranch
```

Be careful if anyone else is using your repo - especially if it's a submodule to some other repo.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do stuff locally first.

One option is to do an interactive rebase and change the commits as you wish then `push -f` it.

`git rebase -i HEAD~10` for last 10 commits

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better served `revert`ing that last commit (i.e. introduce a new commit that reverts the previous one). Once you push to a remote repo you shouldn't be rewriting history. With git, revert has a very specific meaning: create a commit with the reverse patch to cancel it out. This way you don't rewrite any history.

```
git revert sha
```

Then just push normally, as your revert is a new commit, its not a special case for `push`, no need to force anything.

The [`git-revert` manpage](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-revert.html) covers a lot of this in its description. Another useful link from the Git Community Book discussing git-revert is here.